# mvc3 partial views for search, validate, submit final results

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, partial-views, form-submit

I am creating a UI using MVC3 to generate a text file message based on user selections.  User needs to find a patient by ID, then a provider by name from my db, and then initiate the creation of the text file. I have the message generator working if the right objects are passed to it (separate assembly).

I need some help understanding how to implement the search/select/clear logic, and the submission of results to call the generator. (New to MVC3).

I made partial views to display the search results, and I have the basic search results showing up on my Index view.

Issues:

My provider search returns a list of providers by last name & first name, and I need my user to select one, if there are more than one by the name.

How do I put these partial views inside a third, to send their results?

How can I make it possible to clear results in the partials?  How do I make sure that I have a valid value in the partials before I send the result?

Any direction would be helpful.  Thanks.

Here's my HomeController:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private CrdDatabase db = new CrdDatabase(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString_CRD_TEST"].ConnectionString);

    public PartialViewResult PatientSearch(string clinicNumber)
    {
        var patient = db.GetCRDPatientInformation(clinicNumber);
        if (patient != null)
        {
            return PartialView("_PatientSearchResult", patient);  
        }
        // need to determine how to return an error message/validation message.
        return PartialView("_PartialClear");  

    }

    public PartialViewResult ProviderSearch(string lastName, string firstname)
    {
        var providerList = db.GetCRDProviderList(lastName, firstname);
        if (providerList.Count < 1)
        {
            return PartialView("_ProviderSearchResults", providerList);
        }
        return PartialView("_PartialClear");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is the _PatientSearchResult.cshtml partial view:

```
@model Objects.CRDPatientInfo
<table id="searchResults">
<tr>
    <th>
        Clinic Number
    </th>
    <th>
        Last Name
    </th>
    <th>
        First Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Middle Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Date of Birth
    </th>
    <th>
        Admin Gender
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       @Model.clinic_number
    </td>
    <td>
       @Model.pat_name_last
    </td>
    <td>
       @Model.pat_name_first
    </td>
    <td>
       @Model.pat_name_mid
    </td>
    <td>
       @Model.pat_birth_date
    </td>
    <td>
       @Model.pat_gender_code
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The _ProviderSearchResults.cshtml is similar, except it loops through the list in the model.

Here is my Index.cshtml, so far:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Muse Orders Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PatientSearch", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
     HttpMethod = "GET",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
     UpdateTargetId = "searchPatientResults"
 }))
{
    <text>Clinic Number:</text>
    <input type="text" name="clinicNumber" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Clear" />

}       

<table id="searchPatientResults">

</table>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProviderSearch", "Home", new AjaxOptions{
     HttpMethod = "GET",
     InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace,
     UpdateTargetId= "searchProviderResults"
    }))
{
    <text>Provider Last Name:</text>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" />
    <text>Provider First Name:</text>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Clear" />

 }

  <table id="searchProviderResults">

  </table>

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GenerateOrder", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
     UpdateTargetId = "generateOrder"
 }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="patient" />
    <input type="hidden" name="provider" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="GenerateOrder" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Clear" />

 }

<table id="generateOrder">

</table>
```